# How to create custom content type in ECM / alfresco using CMIS?

Tags: alfresco, cmis, opencmis

CMIS 1.1 allows us to create custom document type. I have tried with [https://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-create-type.html]session.createType(). But I am not able figured out. Is there any other tutorial or example code to create type in Alfresco using CMIS 1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a good example to create a custom type: http://ecmarchitect.com/alfresco-developer-series-tutorials/content/tutorial/tutorial.html#creating-content-with-opencmis

I guess you haven't really read the tutorials.

-- UPDATE --

I guess it isn't clearly written in the tutorial. So basically there are 2 major types in CMIS:

- Document Types which inherit their properties from **cmis:document**
- Folder Types which inherit their properties from **cmis:folder**

So let's say our model is called **cntz** as prefix and our inherited **cm:content** type is called `cntz:document` and the folder equivalent is called `cntz:folder`

Document Types are written in this case `"D:cntz:document"`
Folder Types are written in this case `"F:cntz:folder"`

So your CMIS code will look like the following:

```
Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<String, Object>();
properties.put(PropertyIds.OBJECT_TYPE_ID, "F:cntz:folder");
properties.put(PropertyIds.NAME, "Chackde");
Folder folder = session.getRootFolder().createFolder(properties);
```

Comment: Thanks. The tutorial you mentioned is about how to create the content with already predefiend custom type of document. Eg. "D:sc:whitepaper" type of document is already defiened in xml file. I looking for the tutorial to create the custom type of document not a content.

Comment: I've updated the answer. I'm not sure what you mean, you need to know which custom type of folder you're creating. If it isn't there yet, then you need to define it in Alfresco. You can not create a new custom type from CMIS.

Comment: In CMIS 1.1,it's possible to create new custom type. https://chemistry.apache.org/java/examples/example-create-type.html. https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/Dynamic_Models. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Cmis, but with Alfresco. There a folder Dynamic Models. If you put an XML there and activate it, the model gets loaded.